# why would I get EADDRINUSE not from bind() but from listen()?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, bind, listen

In a C++ Linux application I'm calling socket(), bind() and listen(), to create a server socket. Usually if the application is started twice (with same server port), in the second process bind() will fail with EADDRINUSE error. However, now I have a case where bind() has apparently succeeded but the subsequent listen() call has thrown the EADDRINUSE error...

This is probably a rare race condition, but I'd be still interested in what cases it could happen that the second bind() succeeds but the second listen() does not. Does anyone know more about such a case?

This is on 32-bit RHEL 5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about Linux, but on Windows, if a wildcard IP (`INADDR_ANY`, etc) is specified when calling `bind()`, the underlying binding may be delayed until `listen()` or `connect()` is called, as the OS has a better chance of deciding at that time which network interface is best to use. `bind()` will not report an error in that situation.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the explanation. Apparently the rules are:
 listen() will actually reserve the port in the kernel and will raise EADDRINUSE if another process has called listen() on the port; bind() does _not_ reserve the port, but will raise EADDRINUSE if another process has called listen() on the port

Answer (score 1):

`setsockopt(.... SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, ...)` should fix your problem.

See [setsockopt(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) and [socket(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html)

(as to why the second `bind` actually succeeds, no idea... actually this should already fail too)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Sure is, though I think _not only_ `listen` should fail, but already `bind`, before you ever get to `listen`. Though Remy Lebeau's theory about _delayed binding_ is probably the reason, it makes perfect sense anyway.

Comment: Glad we agree.  But then, `SO_REUSEADDR` doesn't *fix* the problem, it hides it.

Comment: I some way no, in some way yes. Since the problem is that two programs cannot use the same port at the same time, there is not really a solution. By giving `SO_REUSEADDR`, you are basically telling the operating system "In case it looks like someone else is still using this port, I promise that it's ok... no other program _really_ uses that port any more". It's somewhat similar to doing a cast in C/C++ where you basically tell the compiler "look, it's ok, I promise that I know what I'm doing".